# Kubectl fails to address correct cluster on EKS and addresses localhost instead

Tags: amazon-eks

I am working on EKS (AWS managed Kubernetes) and any time I try to use kubectl-I receive this message.
What I have done so far to configure the my config:

1. I have set context

   kubectl config set-context arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:myaccountid:cluster/myclustername
2. I have switched to this context

   kubectl config use-context arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:myaccountid:cluster/myclustername
3. Validated that I am indeed in right context

   kubectl config get-contexts

Receieved my arn of a current cluster
And, yes, I have done `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <EKS_Cluster_Name> --region <Region_Name>`
But when I try to use simplest of commands, such as

```
kubectl cluster-info dump
```

Or any other kubectl command, I receive either

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Or

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Why does it try to connect to the localhost if context is set to the specific cluster? How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did

```
kubectl --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config  get nodes
```

And for some reason after I received my nodes it all started working